# can't import scikit-learn - ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size,

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, python-import, valueerror

I am trying to import `scikit-learn` and get this error
[image]
I upgraded `numpy`, `pandas` and `scikit-learn` using `pip` but this didn't help.

Comment: did you tried pip install -U scikit-learn ?

Comment: If you aren't currently using it I would recommend using the Anaconda Python distribution. You can download it here: https://www.continuum.io/downloads . It comes with sklearn and a bunch of other packages preinstalled and it has other benefits too. https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Answer (score 0):

First pip uninstall all the libraries that you mention.
Then go to this web page: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn
Download first numpy+mkl wheel file  for your operating system and install it by using pip.
For instance: `pip install numpy‑1.12.1+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl`
Then pip install pandas.
Finally install the scikit-learn wheel file

Answer (score 0):

So you are using *PyCharm* as I see and also you use *Python console*.

Follow the following:

1. one option is to choose python distribution from your machine to match the one you originally installing the package in terminal on the Project interpreter window.
2. second option is the one with a bit of configuration and installation of the package from the package list window.

***PyCharm/Preferences.../go down on Project:"your_project_name"/Project Interpreter*** and select the interpreter what you need. `Here you can have selected one with the packages aka machine python or you select other one aka virtual env or conda etc`.

one the bottom page \as you can see bellow;
[image: Plus + sign] is a plus sign so that sign will open 'Available Packages' window and on search bar just type **scikit-learn** and  select if you want into your user directory or no and hit *Install Package* button (on left bottom corner location).

[image: Available Packages window with location]

And the results: [image: now works!!!]